# Rearranging Excel Data using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Hello I am trying to reaarange the data in excel using VBA.
Current Data is

```
Project Task    Resource
P1  T1  R1
P1  T1  R2
P1  T3  R3
P1  T3  R4
P1  T3  R5
P2  T6  R6
P2  T7  R7
```

I want it to look like:

```
Project Task    Resource        
P1  T1  R1  R2  
P1  T3  R3  R4  R5
P2  T6  R6      
P2  T7  R7
```

The resources are spread out based on project and task. I wanted to first test project and task and so I wrote:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim rw As Long, cl As Long
    Dim Text As String
    Dim Text2 As String

    With ActiveSheet
        For rw = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlDown).Row To 6 Step 1
            For cl = .Cells(rw, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column To 3 Step 1
                If Not IsEmpty(.Cells(rw, cl)) Then
                    Text = Cells(rw, 1).Value
                    Text2 = Cells(rw + 1, 1).Value
                    If Text = Text2 Then
                        .Columns(cl + 1).Insert
                        .Cells(rw, cl + 1) = .Cells(rw, cl + 1).Value2
                        '.Cells(rw + 1, 2) = .Cells(rw, cl).Value2
                        .Cells(rw, cl).Clear
                    End If

                End If
            Next cl
        Next rw
    End With
End Sub
```

Upon debugging I realized the cursor moves from

```
For rw = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlDown).Row To 6 Step 1
```

to

```
 End With
```

directly.

What am I doing wrong and is there an easy code to do the required thanks.

I changed the code s little:
this is the new code:

```
Sub Test()
Dim rw As Long, cl As Long
Dim Text As String
Dim Text2 As String
Dim Flag As Integer

With ActiveSheet
    For rw = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
        For cl = .Cells(rw, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column To 2 Step -1
            If Not IsEmpty(.Cells(rw, cl)) Then
                Text = Cells(rw, 1).Value
                Text2 = Cells(rw - 1, 1).Value
                If Text = Text2 Then
                    Flag = Flag + 1
                    '.Columns(cl + 1).Insert
                    .Cells(rw, cl + Flag) = .Cells(rw, cl).Value2
                    '.Cells(rw, cl).Clear

                End If

            End If
        Next cl
    Next rw
End With
```

End Sub

The output is nowhere close to what i want:

```
Project Task                    
P1  T1                  
P1  T1                  T1
P1  T3              T3  
P1  T3          T3      
P1  T3      T3          
P2  T6                  
P2  T7  T7
```

Comment: You want to `Step -1`, not `1`. I assume you're trying to work from the last row, up towards row 1?

Comment: `xlDown` should probably be `xlUp` as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I changed to -1 and added xlup. I can transverse through the comment but still do not get the data in re-arranged format

Comment: @Shank, following your edit, I think one big advantage of using the dictionary approach instead, as I suggested in my answer, is that you don't need to keep track of the complexity arising from the fact that the data is rearranged for every iteration of your (nested) for loops. You also avoid the need to check for things like `Text = Text2`. Dictionaries take a little time to get used to, but (unlike constantly rearraning data) they are not very complicated once you've used them a couple of times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a different approach using dictionaries instead to produce the desired result.

The idea is to read the data rows (as strings) to a dictionary, using a key consisting of Project and Task. If the key for a row does not already exist in the dictionary, it will be added. If it already exists, append the additional Resource. Like this, the seven rows of data will produce a dictionary with four string items representing the desired output. The last step is to read the content of the dictionary to the worksheet.

Assuming that the data is located in range A1:C7, the code below produces the result in the following screenshot, with the desired output in range E1:I4.

Note that this requires that you set a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime as shown in the code below.

[image]

```
Sub TestWithDict()
' Requires that the VBA project has a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime;
' choose Tools > References > Microsoft Scripting Runtime
    Dim myDict As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim rngData, rngTarget As Range
    Dim sRowString, sRowKey As String
    Dim sArray() As String
    Dim i, j As Integer

    Set myDict = New Scripting.Dictionary
    Set rngData = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

    ' Loop through the rows:
    For Each rRow In rngData.Rows
        ' Build a string from the row:
        sRowString = rRow.Cells(, 1).Value & ";" & rRow.Cells(, 2).Value & _
            ";" & rRow.Cells(, 3).Value
        ' Use Project and Task to create a key for the dictionary:
        sRowKey = rRow.Cells(, 1).Value & ";" & rRow.Cells(, 2).Value
        ' Save the string to the Dictionary:
        ' 1) If it doesn't already exist, add it:
        If Not myDict.Exists(sRowKey) Then
            myDict.Add sRowKey, sRowString
        ' 2) If it already exists, append the resource from the third column:
        Else
            myDict.Item(sRowKey) = myDict.Item(sRowKey) & ";" & rrow.Cells(, 3).Value
        End If
    Next rrow
    ' After completing the For block, the dictionary contains 
    ' four strings representing each row in the desired output.

    ' Write the strings in the dictionary to the worksheet:
    Set rngTarget = ActiveSheet.Range("E1")
    i = 0
    For Each sItem In myDict.Items
        sArray = Split(sItem, ";")
        Debug.Print sArray(0), sArray(1), sArray(2)
        For j = 0 To UBound(sArray)
            rngTarget.Offset(i, j) = sArray(j)
        Next j
        i = i + 1
    Next sItem
End Sub
```

Comment: Noticed two things. 1. `rRow` and `sitem` needs to be declared when I run Option Explicit 2. `For j = 1 To UBound(sArray)` -> `For j = 0 To UBound(sArray)` , otherwise you loose column A's values when you print them to the new range.

Comment: Very good work of you!!! I have tried for a while now and know how difficult it is. Impressive.

Comment: @Wizhi, I didn't bother to use option explicit, but I probably should have, although it runs smoothly on my screen. I used rRow and sItem as iterators without first declaring them. Try adding Dim statements for both. I discovered dictionaries relatively recently and find them remarkably useful for many things. (A useful comparison of collections and dictionaries can be found here: stackoverflow.com/a/32479872/5457466 )

Comment: And thanks for spotting the typo @Wizhi, I was reusing a screenshot from an earlier run and didn't spot the missing values..!

Comment: I like option explicit. I have noticed that it reduces the error for other people when I present my code :). The code might work on my computer but not on others :/. More than happy that you made it :D!

Comment: Caveat: normally I would avoid `activesheet` and use explicit references instead, like this: `Set rngData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SheetName").UsedRange`, assuming the name of the sheet is known.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If Column C was also based on some correlation as Task and Project then should I add column C to :sRowKey = rRow.Cells(, 1).Value & ";" & rRow.Cells(, 2).Value & rRow.Cells(,3).Value

Comment: If you add column C to the key, every row will have a unique key, and the dictionary will contain seven string rows instead of four, so you would simply recreate the data. In other words, the statement `myDict.Exists(sRowKey)` would evaluate to FALSE for each iteration. Every key in a dictionary must be unique (by definition). I exploited that fact when I chose Project and Task to build the key. In principle you could add more info to the key, but exactly how you do that depends on the actual data that you are working with.

Comment: I altered the code: sRowString = rrow.Cells(, 1).Value & ";" & rrow.Cells(, 2).Value & ";" & rrow.Cells(, 3).Value & ";" & rrow.Cells(, 4).Value & ";" & rrow.Cells(, 5).Value
        ' Use Project and Task to create a key for the dictionary:
        sRowKey = rrow.Cells(, 1).Value & ";" & rrow.Cells(, 2).Value to include more columns but kept the key as first two columns

Comment: changed this aswell: myDict.Item(sRowKey) = myDict.Item(sRowKey) & ";" & rrow.Cells(, 4).Value & ";" & rrow.Cells(, 5).Value & ";" & rrow.Cells(, 6).Value

Comment: Quick followup question: For some reaon its printing/displaying from column B "task" and not from Column A the "project". What am I doing wrong

Comment: @Shank, sounds like a reasonable approach to alter the code for `sRowString` and the dict `key` if that suits your actual data. For the follow-up question, pls note that there was a typo in the original version of my code (spotted by @Wizhi) that might be the culprit for why you didn't see column A, if you copy-pasted the earlier version. In the statement `For j = 0 To UBound(sArray)`, I had wrongly stated `j = 1` instead of `j = 0`. That error meant that column A was not written properly to the worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Sub test()
    Dim d As Object, vS As Variant
    Dim vDB, a, vR()
    Dim s As String
    Dim i As Long, n As Long
    Dim j As Integer, c As Integer


    vDB = Range("a1", Range("c" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    n = UBound(vDB, 1)

    Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For i = 1 To n
        s = vDB(i, 1) & "," & vDB(i, 2)
        If d.Exists(s) Then
        Else
            d.Add s, i
        End If
    Next i
    a = d.keys
    ReDim vR(1 To d.Count, 1 To 10)
    For i = 0 To d.Count - 1
        c = 2
        For j = 1 To n
            s = vDB(j, 1) & "," & vDB(j, 2)
            If s = a(i) Then
                vR(i + 1, 1) = vDB(j, 1)
                vR(i + 1, 2) = vDB(j, 2)
                c = c + 1
                vR(i + 1, c) = vDB(j, 3)
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    Sheets.Add
    Range("a1").Resize(UBound(vR, 1), UBound(vR, 2)) = vR

End Sub
```